# Bulk Insert in Post Deployment Script

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, relative-path, bulkinsert

So, I have a script that uses bulk insert to pull text from files and insert their contents into a table.  I am loading from text files because the text may be large and in doing this, I do not need to worry about escaping.  I have the script working locally with a set defined directory.  ex ('C:\Users\me\Files\File.txt')  But, I need to run this script in a Post Deployment script.  The text files that I am reading from are in the same Database project.  I cannot do a set defined directory as the directory may be different depending on the different environments that the project is published to.  Is there a way to get a relative path or get what the solution/project's directory is after deployment?

Answer (score 1):

So, because Bulk Insert needs an absolute path, scripts have no concept of relative paths, and this will be deployed on multiple environments where I do not know the absolute path.  I decided to utilize Powershell AND Bulk Insert.  So, what I am doing is, on the Database project's Pre-Build, I call my Powershell script.  The Powershell script is able to figure out its current directory.  I build a SQL file that is called in the Post-Deployment script.  In this SQL file, I Bulk Insert using the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use BCP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx ? It can handle relative paths. And if you are able to all PowerShell, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to call BCP.EXE. And it is essentially the same API as `BULK INSERT`.

Comment: I actually need to do a few other things, i.e. other columns/inserts along with loading the text from the files.  Right now, I'm Bulk Inserting into a temp table, then doing a few other things and pulling from the temp table.

Comment: @ScubaSteve : well, you could call `xp_cmdshell` in your proc to import into a global temp table. Just an idea.

Comment: Yeah, just as a standard of practice, I'd like to avoid using global temp tables.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a standard location on the file system?  When I need to write DOS/CMD scripts that are portable (including install stuff for later consumption via T-SQL, such as [CREATE ASSEMBLY FROM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189524.aspx)), I do something like:

```
IF NOT EXIST C:\TEMP\MyInstallFolder (
     MKDIR C:\TEMP\MyInstallFolder
)

REM put stuff into C:\TEMP\MyInstallFolder now that it is certain to be there)

REM CALL some process that looks in C:\TEMP\MyInstallFolder
```

The `MKDIR` will create all missing parent folders. So a folder like `TEMP`, which used to be standard on PCs running Windows, is typically not there anymore since they have moved to per-user temp folders but is created and then `MyInstallFolder` is created, causing no errors.  The `IF NOT EXIST` will make sure that re-running the script will also not error after the first run.

Comment: Yeah, I did think about using the file system.  But, for source control's sake along logical cohesion of where the files should be added/edited, it made sense to put it in the database project.  As far as your cmd suggestion goes, I think I am doing something similar with Powershell.